# How to update a specific element in all documents of a mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

An example of a document from a collection named categories in my MongoDB Database is:

```
{
    "_id": "Cookbooks",
    "parent": "Non-Fiction",
    "ancestors": [
        "Books",
        "Non-Fiction",
        "Cookbooks"
    ]
}
```

All other entries in this category collection have this same schema and there are hundreds of them. What I want to do is insert an additional "All" element at the first position of the **ancestors** array to all those 100 entries/documents. for eg:

```
{
    "_id": "Cookbooks",
    "parent": "Non-Fiction",
    "ancestors": [
        "All",
        "Books",
        "Non-Fiction",
        "Cookbooks"
    ]
}
```

Is there a way that doesn't require writing a complete script and can be done just using the mongo shell or any other simple way? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To push "All" in **ancestors** array at the first position you should use `$postiion: 0` and to update all records should use `multi:true`

in mongoDB:

```
db.collectionName.update({},
   { $push: { "ancestors": {$each: ["All"], $position: 0} }},
   {multi:true})
```

in mongoose :

```
ModelName.update({},
       { $push: { "ancestors": {$each: ["All"], $position: 0} }},
       {multi:true},
       function(err, result) {
          if(err) {
             // return  error
          }
          //return success
});
```

Comment: Hi, Shaishab! Thanks a lot! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can push the value via mongo shell.

Here is the query:

```
db.w6.update(
  { _id: "Cookbooks"},
  { $push: { "ancestors": "All" }}
);
```